# What would be a good way to run a ground from the existing grounded circuit to the new power outlet from another circuit?

Tags: wiring, grounding

So after asking around here I was told that it is OK to run a ground wire from an existing near by power outlet (on a different circuit) to a new power outlet. The layout is below. The garage circuit(to the left) is something that I extended to that end of the garage using PVC conduit.

What is a recommended way to run that wire, given the below layout?

[image]

Update: here are is the type of wire that was used by the previous owner AND a close up of the point where the cable enters the wall to feed the first light and then it exits to go up and head over to the second light.
I rotated the image so you can read the wire specs, in fact the right side is the bottom of the image

My intention is to install a power outlet just below that hole 
I might want to add a switch to shut off the lights when the in house switch is on so I can work with the table saw without having the lights on during the day time.

[image]

Update:
Here is a picture of the box behind the first light (the one to the left). The black (hot) wire seems to have a cracked insulation just where it exits the wall, I had to put some tape there
[image]

Comment: Please review [the list of questions you have already asked](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/19581/minime?tab=questions), and see if your question is on it, before asking a new question.  If you are doing this to "bump" your question and get new eyes on it, that's not allowed here, and editing your old question will do what you want.

Comment: I have not asked about how to run that wire anywhere, I need to know if I need to use conduit, to cover it in some way if there are any norms or regulations dictating how to do this

Comment: Ex: do I run the wire from the case of the outlet that is already there (will look ugly) or could I branch the wire at the elbow level up above that power outlet?

Comment: I have added a picture showing the wires and the hole in the wall allows the cable to reach the first light. See the Update section of my post

Comment: @MiniMe -- are you in Canada?

Comment: yes I am in Ontario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/185137?noredirect=1 I do not need to run a ground wire as my wire already has a ground.

Comment: Have you looked at the insides of the boxes involved to verify that a ground wire is present? Your NMD-90 may predate the requirement for a ground wire...

Comment: Right now is bitter cold (and dark) around here, probably I will try to have a look tomorrow. I don't know if there are any boxes on the garage light circuit. If there are any they must be covered by ceiling and  I have no access to them. I posted about the next step here https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/185139/what-would-be-the-wiring-diagram-to-add-a-receptacle-switch-combo-to-the-outdoor/185142#185142
BTW everything in the house seems to be wired with grounding

Comment: I just updated the question with a picture taken today, I almost lost my fingers with this cold and the metal of the light was even colder. Plus that I had to tape the hot wire which has the insulation cracked