# Is cable marked 14CU 2 CDRS NMD90 two wire or three wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have the below cable in my garage and I am not clear if it is a two or a three wire cable. I was convinced it is a two wire but after researching I am now seeing it could be a three.

[image]

This is related to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/184874/what-would-be-a-good-way-to-run-a-ground-from-the-existing-grounded-circuit-to-t?noredirect=1#comment324465_184874).

Here is the picture that confirms the presence of the ground wire:

[image]

Comment: 14/2 has two conductors and a ground,3 wires in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common type of cable used in houses is technically known as NMD 90 (Non-Metallic Dry service cable rated at maximum of 90 degrees Celsius). It is usually a plastic white covered cable. This cable comes with two or more conductors and includes a ground wire (bare wire).
Your cable has 2 conductors and a ground.